# Calculation of variables from two jquery functions

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to calculate two variables each from different jQuery function and I still don't get a result.
One variable is from radio buttons and second is from input fields.

Here is script:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("input[name='typ_podorysu']").click(function(e) {
    var typ_skrine = parseFloat(jQuery("input[name='typ_podorysu']:checked")
      .attr("data-calc_value") || 0);

    console.log(typ_skrine);
  });
  
  jQuery("input[name='sirka'], input[name='vyska'], input[name='hlbka'], 
      input[name='typ_podorysu']").keyup(function(e) {
    var width = parseFloat(jQuery("input[name='sirka']").val() || 0);
    var depth = parseFloat(jQuery("input[name='hlbka']").val() || 0);
    var height = parseFloat(jQuery("input[name='vyska']").val() || 0);
    var plocha = ((width / 1000) * (depth / 1000) * (height / 1000));
    console.log(plocha + " m2");
  });
});
```

Comment: We need to see the associated HTML in order to debug the issue. I would assume that if the different inputs are groups of radio buttons, then you're missing the `:selected` selector to get the value from the one the user checked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried more options but...the simple way is the way :)
End result is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("input[name='sirka'], input[name='vyska'], input[name='hlbka'], input[name='typ_podorysu']").bind('click keyup', function(e) {
        var width = parseFloat(jQuery("input[name='sirka']").val() || 0);
        var depth = parseFloat(jQuery("input[name='hlbka']").val() || 0);
        var height = parseFloat(jQuery("input[name='vyska']").val() || 0);
        var typ_skrine = parseFloat(jQuery("input[name='typ_podorysu']:checked").attr("data-calc_value") || 0);
        var plocha = (( width / 1000 ) * ( depth / 1000 ) * ( height / 1000)) + typ_skrine;
        console.log(plocha + " m2");
    });
});
```